# These 3 lines of javascript code made me crazy

Tags: javascript

```
var img = new Image();

img.onerror = function () { 
    if (! img) return;
    img = undefined;
    alert("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is UP"); 
}

img.onload = img.onerror;

img.src = "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/123.jpg";

setTimeout(function () { 
    if (! img) return;
    img = undefined;
    alert("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is DOWN"); }, 5000); 
}
```

---

[1] xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is a host, it maybe is up, it maybe is down. This code will check whether it is up or down.

[2] 123.jpg is a non-existent image file.

[3] I completely don't understand the following 3 lines of code

```
if (! img) return;
img = undefined;
alert("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is UP"); or alert("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is DOWN");
```

Can someone explain these 3 lines of code?

Comment: Please try to at least properly indend your code. If you don't understand some code, learn more about the language or ask the person who wrote it for help.

Answer (score 0):

okay lets break it down

```
if (! img) return;
```

if image is not [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)...we exit the function

```
img = undefined
```

we unset the img variable

```
alert("xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is UP");
```

display a pop up with the above text

This seems like a strange way of checking to see whether or not an image exists. I would personally do it this way:

```
var i = new Image()
i.addEventListener('load', function(){alert('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is UP')})
i.addEventListener('error', function(){alert('xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is DOWN')})
i.src="http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/123.jpg";
```

Comment: I think you have an extra *not* in there

Comment: I understand every line of code, but I can't understand the principle of checking a host up or down using this code. Why? I want to know. Thanks.

Comment: it is a bit strange, i have edited my answer to show you how i would do it :/

Comment: Thank you, derp. Your code is concise, but it doesn't work properly, all hosts are "down". "123.jpg" is a non-existent image file, it doesn't exist.

Comment: hmm if it doens't exist, then the error handler is triggered and it will say that the host is down. If you have control over the server, why not create a /ping endpoint that returns some variable. Then if you make a ajax request on that endpoint, you will know whether or not that server is up